# Create a textbox on clickin a button using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an add button 
and I want to set the button to open a text box when is clicked without refreshing the page
I think the solution is javascript 
so please help me

Comment: -1, Please do some research, our job is not to do the work for you. Make some sort of effort.

Comment: open a text box without refreshing the page? No idea what you're talking about :-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `jQuery` if you can. Simply:

Html:

```
<button id="createInput">Create</button>

<div id="textarea"></div>
```

and jQuery:

```
$('#createInput').click(function(){
    $('#textarea').html('<input type="text" />');
    return false;
});
```

**Note:** If you want create new elements on each click on button, replace `html` with `append`

Comment: ok. lets say I have three buttons and they all have same classes.
They are in diiferent part of my website. and when I click on add button it should open a text-box in fron of this add button. i used this code but it's not going to work. what's the problem?
$('.createInput').click(function(){

Answer (score 0):

first set the text box display:none in css,
then 
with jquery

`$('#id-Of-your-button').on('click', function(){
$('Your-text-box').show();
})`

if you want to toggle the visibility use

`$('Your-text-box').toggle();`

Comment: The OP wants to `create` an element. Not to toggle an existing one.

Comment: he can use append function